# Rectangular billiards: ergodic or not?

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-physics, ergodic-theory, chaos-theory, billiards

I'm approaching [dynamical billiards theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards), and I've found that rectangular/square billiards are among the examples of integrable and non-ergodic ones.

But [in this contribution](https://moodle2.units.it/pluginfile.php/202500/mod_resource/content/1/chaos.pdf) it is (resolutely) said that rectangular billiards *are* in fact ergodic.

I'm confused, so any help is welcome

Comment: Every (compact) dynamical system have at least one ergodic invariant measure, so do you mean uniquely ergodic?

Comment: Yes @EtienneBfx. Indeed, I think there's a simpler explanation: some introductory accounts consider ergodicity just in configuration space - and not phase space

Comment: It is just a flow on a torus right?